# Karma/Jasmine – cannot start testing with new Angular 5 project (due tot index.d.ts errors)

Tags: karma-jasmine

When starting the test with ‘ng test’, the Chrome browser won’t start. I get this weird message.

karma jasmine ERROR in node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(138,47): error TS1005: ';' expected.

My Angular version is 5.2 with the CLI 1.7.4.

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: I met the same issue. Currently if you install Angular CLI@1, and ng new to create a new project, you will meet the same issue when running ng test. Don't know how to bypass this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser won’t start if you have errors – that’s what you saw.

Solution 1 – for solving the symptom:

I had the same issue. It may help when you update the typescript and jasmine types like so:

```
$ npm install --save-dev typescript@2.7

$ npm install --save-dev @types/jasmine@2.8.4
```

Solution 2 – more fundamental:

1 – Create a new Angular 5 project. Verify that testing is possible: ‘$ ng test’.

2 – Check the mismatch in versions in your package.json file. Correct these versions of your project according to the new sample project you just created. Do this with ‘npm install --save (or --save-dev)' of the packages. That way you will update the package.json file.

Success!